# How to define deleter similar to getter and setter

Tags: javascript, proxy, metaprogramming

I have a code that does get, set for nested objects using proxy. I want to handle delete also. I'm not sure how to do it.

In the below code, I use proxy to define getter and setter, but I also want to tap whenever a property gets deleted.

```
/*
    This function takes an object and converts to a proxy object.
    It also takes care of proxying nested objectsa and array.
*/
let getProxy = (original) => {
    return new Proxy(original, {
        get(target, name, receiver) {
            let rv = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
            return rv;
        },
        set(target, name, value, receiver) {
            // Proxies new objects 
            if(typeof value === "object"){
                value = getProxy(value);
            }
            return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
        }
    })
}

let first = {};
let proxy = getProxy(first);

/*
    Here are the tests
*/

proxy.name={}                               // object
proxy.name.first={}                         // nested object
proxy.name.first.names=[]                   // nested array 
proxy.name.first.names[0]={first:"vetri"}   // nested array with an object

/*
    Here are the serialised values
*/
console.log(JSON.stringify(first))  // {"name":{"first":{"names":[{"first":"vetri"}]}}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(proxy))  // {"name":{"first":{"names":[{"first":"vetri"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that deleteProperty handler takes care of it

```
/*
    This function takes an object and converts to a proxy object.
    It also takes care of proxying nested objectsa and array.
*/
let getProxy = (original) => {
    return new Proxy(original, {
        get(target, name, receiver) {
            let rv = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
            return rv;
        },
        set(target, name, value, receiver) {
            // Proxies new objects 
            if(typeof value === "object"){
                value = getProxy(value);
            }
            return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
        },
        deleteProperty: function(target, property) {
            if (property in target) {
                delete target[property];
            }
        }
    })
}

let first = {};
let proxy = getProxy(first);

/*
    Here are the tests
*/

proxy.name={}                               // object
proxy.name.first={}                         // nested object
proxy.name.first.names=[]                   // nested array 
proxy.name.first.names[0]={first:"vetri"}   // nested array with an object

/*
    Here are the serialised values
*/
console.log(JSON.stringify(first))  // {"name":{"first":{"names":[{"first":"vetri"}]}}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(proxy))  // {"name":{"first":{"names":[{"first":"vetri"}]}}}
delete proxy.name.first.names[0].first // call goes through the delete handler
```